# Why does C++11 support 6 different regular expression grammars?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std

It appears that C++11 supports a whopping six different regular expression grammars:

- ECMA-262 (ECMAScript) regular expressions (slightly modified?)
- Basic POSIX regular expressions
- Extended POSIX regular expressions
- *awk* regular expressions
- *grep* regular expressions
- *egrep* regular expressions

Why was it decided to include so many options instead of settling on a single grammar? Why these particular 6?

Comment: Because it's just *that* awesome?

Comment: Perl regular expressions ftw!

Comment: Remember, the regular expression languages are all very similar. I'm sure that the engine behind them are all the same with just some minor variations in the parser.

Comment: Because 6 people were at the committee meeting that day?

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not *that* awesome: it lacks PCREs.

Comment: And R. Martinho Fernandes has your answer. Someone will always want to use a different one.

Comment: I think that awk and egrep use extended POSIX regular expressions, and grep uses basic POSIX regular expressions. So basically you have BRE, ERE, and ECMA, which all have published standards. Are any of the other flavors actually well specified, or do you just have to look at the latest implementation of Perl, for example, to find out what it can do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standardization process is all about pragmatism. There are benefits to including a RE grammar in the standard, as long as it's correctly specified, but no benefit to dropping one.

Exclusion would make it easier for a library implementer to apply a "100% C++11 compliant" badge, but who really cares? Nobody should be making that claim anyway, and only ignorant PHBs would be looking for it. Libraries always have bugs which prevent reaching 100%, and a good library has an excess of features.

Note that all the included grammars are specified by already existing international standards. So little effort is needed on the part of the C++ committee. Just §28.13, which is a couple pages long.

If they leave out a standardized grammar, then different Standard Library implementers will add it under different names, resulting in incompatibility. This is unlikely to happen for a grammar which is merely defined by a popular library, where the library implementer will be responsible for the C++ interface, not Standard Library vendors.

Comment: +1 for the why multiple are included. Any thoughts on why these six? I can see having a Perl-like grammar, such as the modified ECMAScript grammar, as many (most?) modern languages have a Perl derived regex grammar. It also make sense to include the two POSIX grammars, since they are standardized and used on Unix-like OSes. However, including the extensions used by awk, grep, and egrep seems rather arbitrary. Does the POSIX C regex API include them? Do other commonly used regex libraries?

Comment: @rkjnsn: All the grammars except ECMAScript are defined by POSIX, including Awk and [e]grep. All the C++11 standard says about them is "refer to POSIX." POSIX defines Awk's grammar in terms of another POSIX grammar: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_04 . So it's not really six supported grammars, but two supported standards.

Comment: ...an old thread I want to add something I don't see mentioned.  A choice of grammars allow for an easier path for porting existing ReGex tasks to C++.  Existing tasks may have gone through a LOT of iterations before the regular expressions are tuned to their needs and cover all of the unusual conditions. Look at all of the attempts to validate an email address out there.  I can see some environments being skittish about porting their application to C++ if they had to start over crafting their patterns again.  But to redo the app and just bring over their existing patterns is a win-win.

Comment: @rkjnsn C was created for the purpose of writing Unix, the developers of awk and grep were associates of Dennis and Ken and both utilities were very heavily used for many years when Unix was considered the only serious operating system. They still get a high amount of use for Linux administration. Mainly due to the nature of C and C++ being more associated with systems level projects than with web dev I would speculate AWK/grep/egrep extensions are are used with good frequency; and secondly they were all written in C.

Answer (score 7):

This is covered by the [TR1 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1429.htm). I will attempt to summarize.

It seemed prudent to build on an existing standard rather than to strike out on their own.

Two existing standards that they could build upon were identified: POSIX REs and ECMAScript REs. Perl REs were left out because they aren’t standardized. (Which reasonable people could disagree with.) Also, ECMAScript REs were seen as an simpler subset of Perl REs which covers the most useful (or perhaps *most used*) features.

Of the two, POSIX REs’ “leftmost longest” implementation did not play well with important features, like non-greedy repeats, and was at odds with how most RE engines work these days.

On the other hand, ECMAScript REs lacked the localization support of POSIX REs. So, they extended ECMAScript REs to include POSIX-RE—style localization support.

POSIX RE support was included as optional since it’s behavior is different enough from ECMAScript REs to justify it being an standard option. The POSIX standard comes with two grammars: Basic and extended. The awk, grep, and egrep REs are all just trivial variations to the basic or extended POSIX grammars rather than truly separate grammars.

So: Two standards, three grammars, six variations.

Answer (score 0):

I think bacause C++ is a multiplatform language. It has produced programs on a variety of programs. And most user expect the program to follow the conventions of for instance the OS.

To solve these problems there are two solutions:

- Make an API for any of those
- Include all popular standards in the language

The second is more elegant because if you change the interface of one API, compatibility problems occur.

For instance POSIX is a Unix standard. Several customers for instance the military ask software companies to make their programs POSIX compatible. There is a story that Microsoft worked several months to change Windows into a POSIX compatible Operating System, only to be able to sell it to the navy.

Comment: POSIX stands for Portable Operating System Interface (the X is for Unix). The operating itself of course doesn't need Regular Expressions. However if you want to do file management one could use a regex to look for files. Most programs who come with Linux/Unix use the POSIX standard for Regular Expressions.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Unix's conventions include regular expressions. Of course, it's the only OS that does so, and its conventions include 5 of the 6.

Comment: Way way back C was created for the purpose of writing Unix, the developers of awk and grep were associates of Dennis and Ken. And all of this predates Windows or Perl.